# Configuring existing django project on a linux shared hosting using cpanel

Tags: django, cpanel

I want to make my django project live. I am having trouble in uploading and running my existing Django project on cpanel.

Comment: Can you give more details? What issues do you encounter? Are there any errors?

Comment: the application site is not opening it is showing that something went wrong